# Xamarin binding for dynamically created buttons from list

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

In the ViewModel I get data from a databank and write some of the data in a list of strings. After that is finished I create buttons in the code behind.
Now I want to bind each of these buttons, so I can do things in the ViewModel when the buttons are clicked.
With the following code it should be clearer what I want to do and how I tried to get to the goal.

In the ViewModel I have a LoadData() method:

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; }

private async Task<bool> LoadData()
{
    Items = new List<string>();
    var data = await getData.Load();

    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    ItemsLoaded?.Invoke(this);
}
```

After that is finished I invoke a method in the code behind, which will create buttons with these items:

```
viewModel.ItemsLoaded += AddItemsToUi;

private void AddItemsToUi(MainPageViewModel vm)
{
    foreach (var item in vm.Items)
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            Text = item,
            TextColor = Color.White
        }
    }
}
```

The code is heavily shortened and anonymized, but I hope it is clear what I want to do.

Let's say I want to change the TextColor of the button which is clicked in Red and the other buttons TextColor in blue.
I thought, I could do that with some kind of binding, but I don't even know where to start really. I need a binding which I can identify somehow. Is this possible?

Edit because of possible duplicate: The duplicate questions just needs a single normal binding. My problem is, that I need to add a binding in a loop, but still want to identify each binded item somehow. I don't know, if that's the right approach or I need something different because that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code in this your Clicked Event get handle and also get Released when page is Disappeared

```
 Button button;
    private void AddItemsToUi(MainPageViewModel vm)
    {
        foreach (var item in vm.Items)
        {
            button = new Button
            {
                Text = item,
                TextColor = Color.White
            };                
            button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (sender as Button);
        button.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        button.Clicked -= Button_Clicked;
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```